# Tire (an elasticsearch client) needs pagination to perform an import, how do I do this with a custom model?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

If I have a simple class like:

```
class Article
  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  property :title,        :analyzer => 'snowball'
  property :published_on, :type => 'date'
  property :tags,         :default => [], :analyzer => 'keyword'

end
```

It seems that I can only perform Article.import if there is a pagination method.  But because this is a custom persistent model and I'm not using ActiveRecord, I am not able to use WillPaginate or Kaminari.  So is there a custom method I can create to support pagination, and if so what requirements must it meet?

Comment: I don't understand the question: from which data store would you like to import `Article` when it's persisted in ES?

Comment: Hi karmi, I want to import from a large hash.  Am I not getting any benefit from the import method over just iterating and inserting myself?

Comment: You can bulk insert from the collection of hashes, you don't have to iterate.

Comment: But the import command fails without a paginate method in the model, doesn't it?

Comment: I've ended up working around this problem, but the original question was how to add in your own paginate method to meet the requirements for import.

Comment: Eg. here, https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/48#issuecomment-1499519

Answer (score 0):

Looking at import method (https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L103-124) looks like there are two options.

- Create a paginate method that gets `per_page` and `page` parameters in options hash.
- Create a map enumerator that returns all documents.

Then looking at `bulk_store` https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L67-79 you have meet some other requirements for the document itself. Look at methods https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L67-79

Comment: No: for models persisted in Tire, import does not make any sense, until there's some `scan` support etc. Or?

Comment: Well I assumed that he had some custom persistence layer, but seems like it's not this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was using mongoid as well and I found that I needed to require 'will_paginate/array' within my environment .rb in order to pull in the records. I don't think you need to use it after that but will_paginate helps with the import process.